# Chrome update message on top of gmail

Tags: google-chrome

I keep getting this on the top whenever I open my gmail.

"This version of Chrome is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a supported browser. Dismiss" Supported browser is button which leads to chrome download page.

I dont have any update suggestion in the browser menu. I have reinstalled chrome twice. I still get this.

What could be the possible reason for this ? Its not bothering me that much though.

Comment: What version *are* you using?

Comment: Version 37.0.2062.124   Update failed (error: 1) I have this error.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty old, mine is v46 - are you the administrator of the machine or is it a work/school/whatever machine?

Comment: I am the administrator. Its my personal computer. Also I have checked https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/111996?hl=en&ref_topic=3421642 . There is no "error: 1" in there !!!

Comment: Hmmm, is the google update service `gupdate` or `gupdatem` running on your machine? In the Task Manager services tab.

Comment: I see both gupdate and gupdatem. Both "stopped". Start up type: Gupdate  - automatic. Gupdatem - Manual. I tried starting. It says "The Google Update Service (gupdatem) service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs". What could be the possible reason for this ? How do I solve this ?

Comment: That seems fine. I read that some people have your issue if some of the chrome configuration files are not in their default locations, but I can't really help you with figuring that out. Maybe if you completely uninstall and remove all trace of chrome from your machine, then reinstall it again?